# Using unwind in multiple nested arrays in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have stored objects in my mongodb(version 3.2) collection in the following schema,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a42b5b7e79d1c0c533f1f"),
    "instanceId" : "i-b385a9bd",
    "DiskSpaceAvailable" : {
        "Datapoints" : [ 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:14:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 4.32112884521484,
                "Unit" : "Gigabytes"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:32:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 4.32107543945312,
                "Unit" : "Gigabytes"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:50:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 4.32101821899414,
                "Unit" : "Gigabytes"
            }
        ]
    },
    "DiskSpaceUsed" : {
        "Datapoints" : [ 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:14:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 3.33073806762695,
                "Unit" : "Gigabytes"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:32:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 3.33079147338867,
                "Unit" : "Gigabytes"
            }
        ]
    },
    "MemoryUsed" : {
        "Datapoints" : [ 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:14:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 0.753532409667969,
                "Unit" : "Gigabytes"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:32:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 0.753063201904297,
                "Unit" : "Gigabytes"
            }
        ]
    },
    "MemoryUtilization" : {
        "Datapoints" : [ 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:18:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 19.5049320125989,
                "Unit" : "Percent"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:36:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 19.5078950721357,
                "Unit" : "Percent"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:54:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 19.5068086169722,
                "Unit" : "Percent"
            }
        ]
    },
    "DiskSpaceUtilization" : {
        "Datapoints" : [ 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:18:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 42.9914921714092,
                "Unit" : "Percent"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:36:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 42.9921815029693,
                "Unit" : "Percent"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:54:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 42.992920072498,
                "Unit" : "Percent"
            }
        ]
    },
    "SwapUtilization" : {
        "Datapoints" : [ 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:18:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 0,
                "Unit" : "Percent"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:36:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 0,
                "Unit" : "Percent"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:54:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 0,
                "Unit" : "Percent"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T13:12:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 0,
                "Unit" : "Percent"
            }
        ]
    },
    "SwapUsed" : {
        "Datapoints" : [ 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T13:06:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 0,
                "Unit" : "Gigabytes"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T13:24:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 0,
                "Unit" : "Gigabytes"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:36:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 0,
                "Unit" : "Gigabytes"
            }
        ]
    },
    "MemoryAvailable" : {
        "Datapoints" : [ 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:14:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 3.10872268676758,
                "Unit" : "Gigabytes"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:32:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 3.10919189453125,
                "Unit" : "Gigabytes"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:50:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 3.10895538330078,
                "Unit" : "Gigabytes"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to use mongodb aggregate and following is my query

```
db.collectionSchema.aggregate([
    {
     $match :{ "instanceId" : "i-b385a9bd" }
    },
    {
      $unwind : "$DiskSpaceAvailable.Datapoints"   
    },
     {
      $unwind : "$DiskSpaceUtilization.Datapoints"   
    },
    {
      $unwind : "$DiskSpaceUsed.Datapoints"   
    },
    {
      $unwind : "$MemoryUsed.Datapoints"   
    },
    {
      $unwind : "$SwapUtilization.Datapoints"   
    },
    {
      $unwind : "$MemoryAvailable.Datapoints"   
    },
    {
      $unwind : "$MemoryUtilization.Datapoints"   
    },
    {
      $unwind : "$SwapUsed.Datapoints"   
    },
    {
      $group : { _id : "$instanceId" , 
               DiskSpaceAvailable : { "$avg" : "$DiskSpaceAvailable.Datapoints.Average" } , 
               DiskSpaceAvailableUnit : { "$addToSet" : "$DiskSpaceAvailable.Datapoints.Unit" },
               DiskSpaceUtilization : {"$avg" : "$DiskSpaceUtilization.Datapoints.Average"},
               DiskSpaceUtilizationUnit : {"$addToSet" : "$DiskSpaceUtilization.Datapoints.Unit"},
               DiskSpaceUsed : {"$avg" : "$DiskSpaceUsed.Datapoints.Average"},
               DiskSpaceUsedUnit : {"$addToSet" : "$DiskSpaceUsed.Datapoints.Unit"},
               MemoryUsed :{"$avg" : "$MemoryUsed.Datapoints.Average"},
               MemoryUsedUnit:{"$addToSet" : "$MemoryUsed.Datapoints.Unit"},
               SwapUtilization:{"$avg" : "$SwapUtilization.Datapoints.Average"},
               SwapUtilizationUnit:{"$addToSet" : "$SwapUtilization.Datapoints.Unit"},
               MemoryAvailable:{"$avg" : "$MemoryAvailable.Datapoints.Average"},
               MemoryAvailableUnit:{"$addToSet" : "$MemoryAvailable.Datapoints.Unit"},
               MemoryUtilization:{"$avg" : "$MemoryUtilization.Datapoints.Average"},
               MemoryUtilizationUnit: {"$addToSet" : "$MemoryUtilization.Datapoints.Unit"},
               SwapUsed:{"$avg" : "$SwapUsed.Datapoints.Average"},
               SwapUsedUnit: {"$addToSet" : "$SwapUsed.Datapoints.Unit"}
               }  
    },
        {
            $project : { _id:1 , 
              DiskSpaceAvailable:1 , 
              DiskSpaceAvailableUnit : 1,
              DiskSpaceUtilization : 1,
              DiskSpaceUtilizationUnit : 1,
              DiskSpaceUsed : 1,
              DiskSpaceUsedUnit : 1,
              MemoryUsed :1,
              MemoryUsedUnit:1,
              SwapUtilization:1,
              SwapUtilizationUnit:1,
              MemoryAvailable:1,
              MemoryAvailableUnit:1,
              MemoryUtilization:1,
              MemoryUtilizationUnit: 1,
              SwapUsed:1,
              SwapUsedUnit:1
              }
        }
    ]);
```

This query does not return and runs indefinitely, I have tried with top 4 unwind operators it works takes about 3-4 seconds but after adding in the 5th unwind operator the query goes for a toss and does not return.
I am sure I am doing something wrong but unable to put a finger on it, can someone please point out if I am making a mistake.

Any kind of suggestions are most welcome, I am willing to change the schema as well.

Thank you :)

Comment: Why will it return? This is like running mapReduce on 300 millions documents and expect it to return in 1 millisecond.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What version of mongod are you on?

Comment: Any suggestions, shall i use different collections for different data then ?

Comment: version 3.2, i am trying to get average of datapoints with their units for each data header

Comment: @sstyvane you were right, I changed my schema back then...it was a total misunderstanding at my end earlier...thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's hell lot of data in a single document. Unwinding this many nested docs and computing the average for the same not only adds to the response time but also to the consumed resources!

To make your **aggregate** query subsequently fast, I insist you should try doing an **average** while inserting the doc instead of doing it on retrieval.

**E.g.**- While adding the 1st doc (the average is 5), the overall average of **DiskSpaceAvailable** will be 5 & when second sub doc is added (with average 2), the total average is computed as 5+2/2 = 3.5.

**The data design will be something like** :-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("585a42b5b7e79d1c0c533f1f"),
    "instanceId" : "i-b385a9bd",
    "DiskSpaceAvailableUnit": "Gigabytes",
    "DiskSpaceAvailableAverage": <The computed average value>,
    "DiskSpaceAvailable" : {
        "Datapoints" : [ 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:14:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 4.32112884521484,
                "Unit" : "Gigabytes"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:32:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 4.32107543945312,
                "Unit" : "Gigabytes"
            }, 
            {
                "Timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-20T12:50:00.000Z"),
                "Average" : 4.32101821899414,
                "Unit" : "Gigabytes"
            }
        ]
    },
    ....
}
```

So, you will just have to fetch the data without doing any kind of computation & the response will also be quite fast(much less compared to your current response time).

Though, Such a structure will subsequently increase the computation times & complexity for inserts/updates. But if faster retrieval is of prime importance then you should take this structure into consideration.